There is a problem while Extruding
While extruding a plane (which is a import image as plane) I am having texture issues.
there is also no option opened for back culling or anything like that. but for the people curious about the settings I took a screenshot of the whole blender:


Did you check the normals ? Alt+N > Recalculate Outside

okay thanks @TheLabCat That was exactly the same solution I need, sorry that I don't know that much of blender terminology to find the question. thanks again!
